# Adding a bathroom

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I’m trying to and a small bathroom. Is it possible to put another toliet and drain on this stack? [image]
Also I can’t have the pipes much lower where I was standing to take the picture because it is where you walk. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand what you have, and what you want. Would you add a plan view diagram of both? Thanks.

Comment: Bathroom in this location, on an upper floor, above this stack, different part of the upper floor? You could cut out what you have and re-do some of it, but again, location of the bathroom is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The new bathroom we want to put in is too far from this stack 12+ feet. I’m looking into something called magic vent by RectorSeal.